# Still receiving error for unique key when using key extractor

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to create a list of items in react native, but I am still getting the error "Each child in a list should have a unique key" even though the keyExtractor prop is being called. It only happens on the first render, which made me think it was a timing issue? I added some loaders, but I'm still getting the error. I've doubled checked that every key is unique, and they are.

Here is the code:

```
{showAllItems &&
 [items?.length > 0 ?
    <FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListHeaderComponent={<View style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />}
      ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ marginBottom: 200 }} />}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <SingleFeedCard data={item} reload={getUser} />
        )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      :
      <Text style={styles.text}>
         Follow people or write a post to fill your Feed.
      </Text>
   ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

You are rendering `Flatlist` inside an array `{showAllItems && [` which means `Flatlist`  itself should have a `key`

```
{showAllItems &&
 [items?.length > 0 ?
    <FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListHeaderComponent={<View style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />}
      ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ marginBottom: 200 }} />}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <SingleFeedCard data={item} reload={getUser} />
        )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      :
      <Text style={styles.text}>
         Follow people or write a post to fill your Feed.
      </Text>
   ]}
```

#### Solution

```
{showAllItems &&
 items?.length > 0 ?
    <FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListHeaderComponent={<View style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />}
      ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ marginBottom: 200 }} />}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <SingleFeedCard data={item} reload={getUser} />
        )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      :(
      <Text style={styles.text}>
         Follow people or write a post to fill your Feed.
      </Text>
   )}
```